# Sketching a function $f(z) = (1-i)z + 3 $ on the complex plane. Am I doing it right?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So I have no problem skeching a set defined on the complex plane. But I don't know how to sketch a function. In my example I have: $f(z) = (1-i)z + 3 $ .

I know that multiplying a complex number by 1-i increases its magnitude by $|1-i|=\sqrt{2} $ and rotates it by π/4 (the argument is increased by π/4). Then adding a 3 should "push" the function 3 points to the left side.

Ultimatelly I should have a function of f(z) rotated by π/4 and moved 3 points to the left side. Am I right? Or is there an error in my way of thinking?

Comment: See @cosmo5's comment for small errors in your thinking, apart from which you are right. Sketching will require a different method than usual, however, since a graph would need to be 4d, which is impossible to draw in the usual way. But you can draw a grid on the complex plane and then visualize the function by drawing the image of the grid next to it (so a rotated, shifted grid).

Comment: @cosmo5 $\arg(1-i) = 7\pi/4$ (or equivalently $-\pi/4$), not $3\pi/4$

Comment: Arg$(1−i)=\color{red}{-}\pi/4$ actually. And +3 means parallelogram addition of vector $z$ with 3, which lies along +ve x-axis. So it's shifting $3$ units to the right, not left.

Comment: Right @jjagmath. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(z)=(1+i)z+3$ rotates $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and shifts $(3,0)$ to the right values $z\in\mathbb{C}$

[image]